# swapping the content inside and outside of the brackets with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, replace

I would like to swap the content of inside and outside of the brackets

```
some outside text (some inside text) some other outside text (some inside text)
```

I tried:

```
text="some outside text (some inside text) some other outside text (some inside text)"
p=re.compile('(?P<before>.*?)\((?P<innertext>.*?)\)(?P<after>.*)')
print(p.sub("(\g<before>)\g<innertext>(\g<after>)",text))
```

but it only applies to the first match

```
>>>(some outside text )some inside text( some other outside text (some inside text))
```

Comment: Just miss out the `after` bit from the pattern and replacement. You are not wanting the regex to match the whole string.

Comment: @PatrickArtner no, `re.sub` will replace multiple matches; the only problem here is including the remaining text as part of the match, which then prevents it from being part of a later match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex is just a bit too complicated. drop the 'after' group and things should work fine

```
import re

text = """\
some outside text (some inside text) some other outside text (some inside text)\
again (some text) outside outside outside (inside here) bla bla\
"""

print(re.sub(r"(?P<before>.*?)\((?P<innertext>.*?)\)", "(\g<before>)\g<innertext>", text))
```

prints

```
(some outside text )some inside text( some other outside text )some inside text(again )some text( outside outside outside )inside here bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

All that you have to do is remove the "after" part from your regexp to ensure that the regexp only matches the part that you are interested in replacing with each match, and then there will be multiple matches replaced.  By including the "after" part in your regexp, the whole string is matched on the first match, and nothing more happens after that.

```
text = "some outside text (some inside text) some other outside text (some inside text)"
p = re.compile('(?P<before>.*?)\((?P<innertext>.*?)\)')
print(p.sub("(\g<before>)\g<innertext>",text))
```

gives

```
(some outside text )some inside text( some other outside text )some inside text
```

Though you might also want to handle the whitespace slightly differently:

```
>>> p = re.compile('\s*(?P<before>.*?)\s*\((?P<innertext>.*?)\)')
>>> p.sub("(\g<before>) \g<innertext> ",text).strip()
'(some outside text) some inside text (some other outside text) some inside text'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what if it starts with ( like 
text="(some inside text) some other outside text (some inside text) some other outside text"

Comment: Then it won't work, because your regexp is set up to look for the outside text first. It might be easiest to test the first character and then apply different regexp depending whether it is `(`, rather than try to combine everything into a single regexp. Also if it is, then in your group for the outside text you will have to use `[^(]*` in place of `.*?` so that you match everything up to the start of the next `(`.